# Relationships in nHibernate using simple columns, not PKs

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I have a table T1 that has these columns:

- ID (int) - is a primary Key
- Ref (int) - (not null)
- Name (string)

And a second table T2 with columns:

- T2ID (int) - is a primary key
- Value1 (int)
- Value2 (int)
- SomeOtherData (int)

Each record from T1 has >2 records in T2: Ref column in T1 has a value from T2 table, T2ID column.

How to write mapping file for this scenario?
Currently I use this:

```
<class name="Class1" table="T1" >
    <id name="ID" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>

        <set name="Data" inverse="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="T2ID"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Class2"/>
        </set>
</class>

<class name="Class2" table="T2" >
    <id name="ID" column="T2ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Value1"/>
    <property name="Value2"/>
    <property name="SomeOtherData"/>
</class>
```

in code I have this to load T2 data for T1:

```
NHibernateUtil.Initialize( class1.Data );
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
SELECT 
T2ID, Value1, Value2, SomeOtherData
FROM T2
WHERE T2ID = <**an ID column from T1 for which I'm loading T2 data!**>
```

The problem is how to tell nHibernate to use a value from Ref column to load Data property, not PK?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn't supported. The [property-ref](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping/1nr4enxv3dpeq/8#5%282E%291%282E%299%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29property) element allows you to map this type of relationship from the "many" side but there's no equivalent for mapping the "one" side.

A workaround is to create a view for T1 that includes T2ID and map that instead of the table.

Comment: A problem is that I will have to update both of these tables... 
I was aware of this, but it seems I will have to use stored procedures :(

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, and probably others, allow for inserts and updates to views if they have a PK.

Comment: We're using SQL Server 2005 SP3, but are looking into SQLLite replacement.

Found a solution which is not so good, but at least it works:

Created a table T3 that has one column - T3ID, Ref in T1 is a FK for T3.T3ID column, T3ID is the same data that T2 table has in T2ID column.

Class1 has a BaseData property which wraps T3 table and BaseData has Data property.